# How can I set default value for bean with String type?

Tags: spring

I have a bean

```
<bean id="directoryName" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

I need to set default value for it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since String has a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(java.lang.String)):

```
<bean id="directoryName" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="DEFAULT_VALUE"/>
</bean>
```